# returning rownumber() as part of the query

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have an SQL Query which is returned to a datatable dtStories (c#).

```
with records as (select row_number() over (order by pages.createdate desc)as 'row', 
field1, field2...etc. from records where row between 1 and 7
```

(There are other instances where i'll need "nth" row or between x & y rows, hence I'm not using a simple select top 7 query.)

I was trying to do slightly different things based on which row it was, so I was querying row[0] thinking this would have the row number in. But, checking the returns in my SQL Server, it actually only returns field 1, field 2... etc which is obviously why my

```
foreach (Datarow row in dtStories)
{
  if (row[0].ToString() == "1")
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

doesn't work.

Is there a way to either make sure row is returned as part of the SQLQuery into the DataTable, or using c# just access row1, row2 etc. of the table?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't show the whole select statement so it is IMPOSSIBLE to know what you are actually doing.  We can tell this because the `(` and `)` don't match.

I expect your code (indented to make clear) looks something like this:

```
with records as 
(
   select row_number() over (order by pages.createdate desc)as 'row', 
          field1, field2 -- ...
   from original_table
)
select  
    field1, field2 -- ...
from records
where row between 1 and 7
```

now it should be clear... to include the row column you need it in the 2nd select list (outside the CTE)

```
with records as 
(
   select row_number() over (order by pages.createdate desc)as 'row', 
          field1, field2 -- ...
   from original_table
)
select  row, -- here!
    field1, field2 -- ...
from records
where row between 1 and 7
```

Comment: you are correct - yes sorry, a bad copy paste that was indeed my code and i had stupidly forgotten to select row in the last part. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

dont understand if your `with records ..` is sql server or c# code. Doesnt look sql because doesnt have closing parenthesis and doesnt have select.

`WITH` is call CTE, and CTE are temporaly created in memory.

You want something like

```
 with records as 
    (
      select row_number() over ....
    )
 SELECT *
 FROM records
```